# innerText doesnt work, a simple clock

Tags: javascript, html

UPDATE**

I found out that clockDiv = null I have no clue why this is tho

ORIGINAL POST**

I tried to make a simple digitalclock.  All that worked but printing my Var in a DIV seems to give me a lot of trouble. For some reason the code stops when I use innerText. Its probably a simple fix yet I don't see the mistake.

```js
function displayTime() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

  // This gets a "handle" to the clock div in our HTML
  var clockDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("clock")[0];

  // Then we set the text inside the clock div 
  // to the hours, minutes, and seconds of the current time
  clockDiv.innerText = (hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

  setInterval(displayTime, 999);
}

// This runs the displayTime function the first time
displayTime();
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="mainpagejavascript.js"></script>
        <title>Raspberry Pi Connect</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1> Raspberry Pi Connect</h1>
        </header>
        <form method="post">
            Name:<input type="text" name="text"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
        <div class='clock'></div>
        <div class="alarmcollect">
            <hr/>
            <h4 class="AlarmHeader"> Alarm Times!</h4>
            <hr/>
            <p>9:00</p>
            <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Set Alarm</span></button>
        </div>
        <p class="AlarmTimes">Alarm Times:</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I pasted your code into a snippet and it appears to work fine

Comment: oh this is weird so the problem must be in the rest of my code. Because on my project the clock doesnt show. Give me a second I will try to look for another problem If I dont find I will post another ;)

Comment: This is rather odd it show in the snippet but not in my browser if I run the same code

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser's console?

Comment: `mainpagejavascript.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of undefined
    at displayTime (mainpagejavascript.js:12)
    at mainpagejavascript.js:18`

Comment: Quick note (not related to your problem): Calling `setInterval` at the end of your function is not what you want to do. You're using it as if it were `setTimeout`. One call to `setInterval` is enough to keep calling the callback at intervals. As it is, it keeps attaching more and more timer listeners. I noticed this after running your example caused my browser to consume lots of CPU.

Comment: Thats very handy! Thank you! I was wondering why my browser was overloading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that by placing your script tag into the head it gets executed before the rest of the document (including the clock div) got loaded. Therefore `clockDiv` is undefined and accessing `innerText` results in throwing an exception, which stops execution (before the interval is set).

One solution would be to attach an event listener to the `DOMContentLoaded` event (and for IE8/9 to `readystatechange`), or (probably simplier) move the script tag to the end of the body.